# Auto It Script Debugging

Tags: autoit

I have a simple script that works on my PC but not on three others. I am running the script directly from SciTE on all the machines, including my own. Anyway, is there something I can turn on to see what's happening?

Script:

```
While True
WinSetOnTop("[TITLE:Production Floor Display]","", 1)
Sleep(20000)
WinSetOnTop("[TITLE:Production Floor Display]","", 0)
WinSetOnTop("[TITLE:Preview Image]","", 1)
Sleep(5000)
WinSetOnTop("[TITLE:Preview Image]","", 0)
Wend
```

Comment: check the return value: `$iReturn=WinSetOnTop("[TITLE:Production Floor Display]","", 1)` and `if $iReturn = 0 Then MsgBox(0,"Error","Window not found")`. Are you sure, the Title is the same on all four PCs?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not natively.

What are you trying to achieve?

Try compiling the program before doing anything else.

If that is what it looks like (something to do with an industrial camera feed), then you're better off just using Javascript, PHP, NGINX and HTML. That would also be uncomparable to your approach in terms of reliability.